# push.default set to matching with multiple remote repositories

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull, git-flow

Recall that:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git //Set a new remote

git remote -v //Verify new remote

origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)
```

Onto local branches, we can set a default policy for `git push` and `git pull` configuring the parameter `push.default`. For example one policy is `matching`:

```
git config --global push.default matching
```

as result, every time we execute `git push`, this will push all name-matching branches of the local repository to the remote repository `origin`.

## Question

If there are more remotes (i.e. not only `origin`) how the policy `matching` apply?

Answer (score 1):

No, `git push` will not push all matching branches. If you push a branch and you do not have configured or given to what it should be pushed, this branch will be pushed to a name-matching branch. If you do `git push --all` it will push all to either the configured push location or otherwise to name-matching branches. But no matter what you also either have configured to which remote to push or you give it on the commandline e. g. with `git push --all origin`. The `push.default` setting only cares about matching branchnames. It does not care about selecting which remote to push to.